# Retornando Campos de Tabela MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Tenho tres tabelas:

```
profissional (id, nome, idtratamento)
usuários (id, nome idtratamento)
formulario (id, data, idprofissional,idusuario)
```

e outra:

```
tratamento (id, descricao)
```

Estou precisando retornar a seguinte informação consultado a tabela formulario:

```
IdFormulario | Data |  NomeProfissional | NomeUsuario 

   ...            ...       Msc. João      Sr. José
```

fazendo o relacionamento entre as tabelas profissional e tratamento, usuario e tratamento, como proceder para o tratamento (Msc, Sr, Srta, etc) retornar na consulta? Consigo retornar apenas 1 tratamento ou para profissional ou para usuário.
Como faço para retornar os tratamentos em mesma consulta sql

SQL:

```
SELECT p.nome, u.nome, f.id, f.data, t.nome as tratamentouser
FROM formulario as f inner join tratamento as t on t.id = f.idusuario inner 
join profissional as p on p.id = f.idprofissional
```

Comment: Qual o relacionamento entre profissional e usuário?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso você precisaria realizar o `join` com a tabela tratamento 2 vezes, sua query ficaria parecida com essa abaixo:

```
SELECT  tp.descricao as tratamentProfissional, p.nome, tu.descricao as tratamentoUser, u.nome, f.id, f.data
FROM formulario as f 
    inner join profissional as p 
        on p.id = f.idprofissional
    inner join tratamento as tp
        on tp.id = f.idtratamento 
    inner join usuario as u 
        on p.id = f.idusuario
    inner join tratamento as tu 
        on tu.id = u.idtratamento
```

Observando que `tp` é o `join` entre profissional e tratamento e `tu` o `join` entre usuario e tratamento